# SQL Server : OR statement within CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I have a stored procedure that is querying some employee records based on what the user sends over.

On the UI, the user will enter multiple data points such as email addresses, User ID's, or Employee Names. This stored procedure checks what datatype they are providing and then searches that field in the database for the records.

Input to stored procedure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <data>
      <dataPoints>
         <dataPoint>
            <order>0</order>
            <value>Jim Bob</value>
         </dataPoint>
         <dataPoint>
            <order>1</order>
            <value>Sally Jones</value>
         </dataPoint>
      </dataPoints>
   </data>
</root>
```

Query:

```
    @dataType VARCHAR (20), @data XML
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN

    -- Create a temp table 
    DECLARE @dataSet TABLE (data VARCHAR(100), [order] INT);

    INSERT INTO @dataSet( data , [order] )
        SELECT  
            ParamValues.x1.value('value[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') ,
            ParamValues.x1.value('order[1]', 'INT') 
        FROM 
            @data.nodes('/root/data/dataPoints/dataPoint') AS ParamValues(x1)

    -- Search Employees
    SELECT 
        ec.FirstName, ec.PreferredName, ec.LastName,
        ec.NTID, ec.QID,
        ec.DepartmentName, ec.SegmentName,
        ec.CenterName, ec.RoleName, ec.MarketName,
        ec.IncentivePlanName,
        ec.CostCenterID,
        ec.SupFirstName, ec.SupPreferredName, ec.SupLastName,
        ec.SiloName,
        ec.AreaName,
        ec.PersonnelID,
        d.[order]
    FROM
        Resources.emp.EmployeeComplete AS ec
    INNER JOIN
        @dataset AS d ON d.data = CASE 
                                     WHEN @dataType = 'NTID' THEN ec.ntid 
                                     WHEN @dataType = 'QID' THEN ec.QID 
                                     WHEN @dataType = 'Emp ID' THEN ec.EmpID 
                                     WHEN @dataType = 'Email Address' THEN ec.Email 
                                     WHEN @dataType = 'Personnel ID' OR @dataType = 'Sap ID' THEN ec.PersonnelID 
                                     --WHEN @dataType = 'Name' THEN (
                                     -- (ec.FirstName + ' ' + ec.LastName) 
                                     --     OR (ec.PreferredName + ' ' + ec.LastName)
                                     --     OR (ec.LastName + ', ' + ec.FirstName)
                                     --     OR (ec.LastName + ', ' + ec.PreferredName
                                     -- )
                        END
    FOR XML PATH ('employees'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT ('root');
```

In short, I take the multiple data points being searched and throw them into an XML string to pass to the stored procedure. Once they arrive,  I put them into a temp table so that I can join that with my main employee records.

The problem / question:

You will see I have some commented out code in my example and this is where my issue is. There are three name fields in my database. `First Name`, `Preferred Name`, `Last Name`.

I essentially need to test what the user provided and find employees based on the combination they entered them. All the user selects in the UI is that they are providing a name but not the format that its in.

For this reason, I need to check to see if I can find records in a couple of different formats.

Issue in this case is that I can't join my dataset using `OR` conditions in the `CASE` statement.

If `@dataType = 'Name'`, I need to be able to join my temp table on a couple of the different combination possibilities.

The one thing we do make them aware of is that they can't mix and match. Meaning they cant do a `FirstName LastName` with a `LastName FirstName` search.

I had trouble explaining this so please let me know if I need to somehow clarify.

Comment: Have you considered using dynamic SQL to build your query? That way, you end up with a simpler SQL statement that just has the relationships you need for each set of parameters.

Comment: You can only set one value per row for `d.data`. It's not a comparison situation, so `OR` isn't appropriate in a `SELECT`. You are `SELECT`ing a record. Do you want to return multiple rows for each of the name formats? Do you want to return those multiple results in a single row as a delimited record?

Comment: @Shawn - Each record returned will be one or more employee records depending on what it finds. If `Name` is used and I search for `Tom Jones` and `Sam Smith`, if it finds any employees with those names, it would return them.

Comment: @DeanOC  - If it comes down to it, I may have to. Was hoping there was just some type of structure I wasn't thinking of to handle this last possibility of searching by name.

Comment: When it returns multiple names, how do you want those displayed? Do you want rows with the other data repeated, or do you want a delimited list returned in one row for the main record?

Answer (score 0):

Push the equations in the `CASE`. If they are true let the `THEN` return 1. Check if the `CASE` returned 1. If and only if it did, you've found a match. In the conditions of `WHEN` you can use Boolean operators. So you can build your `OR` (or use `IN` as i did below) there.

```
...
CASE 
WHEN @dataType = 'NTID' AND d.data = ec.ntid THEN 1
WHEN @dataType = 'QID' AND d.data = ec.QID THEN 1
...
WHEN (@dataType = 'Personnel ID' OR @dataType = 'Sap ID') AND d.data = ec.PersonnelID THEN 1
WHEN @dataType = 'Name' AND (d.data IN ('' + ec.FirstName + ' ' + ec.LastName, 
                                        '' + ec.PreferredName + ' ' + ec.LastName,
                                        '' + ec.LastName + ', ' + ec.FirstName,
                                        '' + ec.LastName + ', ' + ec.PreferredName) THEN 1
END = 1
...
```

Comment: Is this still within my `join` (the same place I have it now) or do I need to move it?

Comment: @SBB: I can replace the old `CASE`, so stay in exactly the same spot.

Comment: Gave this a shot but getting an SQL error. `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Billy Bob' to data type int.`

Comment: @SBB: Hmm, I guess that can only be form the `+`. I tried to force string context be adding the empty string first (see the edit). If that doesn't help try `convert()` or `cast()`. Or look where else this comes from. (I assume none the columns in the `CASE`, that come from one of your tables is `inetger`?)

Comment: I think you need escaped single quotes around each of the `IN` conditions. `''' + ec.FirstName + ' ' + ec.LastName + '''` And possibly a `coalesce()` or `isNull()` to account for `NULL`s.

Answer (score 0):

What about just putting ORs in your join?

```
FROM    @dataset AS d
        INNER JOIN Resources.emp.EmployeeComplete AS ec
        ON (@dataType = 'NTID' AND ec.ntid = d.data)
            OR (@dataType = 'QID' AND ec.QID = d.data)
            OR (@dataType = 'Emp ID' AND ec.EmpID = d.data)
            OR (@dataType = 'Email Address' AND ec.Email = d.data)
            OR ((@dataType = 'Personnel ID' OR @dataType = 'Sap ID') AND ec.PersonnelID = d.data)
            OR (@dataType = 'Name' AND (ec.FirstName + ' ' + ec.LastName) = d.data)
            OR (@dataType = 'Name' AND (ec.PreferredName + ' ' + ec.LastName) = d.data)
            OR (@dataType = 'Name' AND (ec.LastName + ', ' + ec.FirstName) = d.data)
            OR (@dataType = 'Name' AND (ec.LastName + ', ' + ec.PreferredName) = d.data)
```

I'm not sure if SQL is smart enough to use the proper indexes on those fields if you have them, probably especially not when combining columns.  You would create indexed views for those combined names, or computed columns you could index on.  It may be better to spread them out into separate queries in if/thens so SQL could optimize each query based on the field you are joining on and just execute the one query.